# Ameritrade API to get account value

Tags: api, stock, ameritrade

Is there an API call to Ameritrade services to pull account value? I don't need other data, just how much is in my account (total). What is the URL and how do I authenticate?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all of this information in their developer docs. Additionally, they have a simple UI where you can test request and generate request/responses.
https://developer.tdameritrade.com/apis

Use the Authentication method to get oAuth bearer token. This token will be used in a request header to access other APIs such as *Get Account*.
https://developer.tdameritrade.com/authentication/apis/post/token-0

*Get Account* endpoint to access balances, positions, and orders for a particular account
https://developer.tdameritrade.com/account-access/apis/get/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D-0